# Развернуть из панели задач

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим я свернул в панель задачи программу, как мне при нажатии какой то кнопки в другом окне, развернуть окно?

Приложение одно и тоже просто в нем два окна.

Comment: Если другое приложение запущено в другом процессе, то никак.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov неправильно выразился, приложение одно, в нем 2 окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Через [StageHelper.getStages()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/stage/StageHelper.java#StageHelper.getStages%28%29) вы можете получить
   необходимый вам Stage.
2. Получите [Window](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/glass/ui/Window.java) этого Stage. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749463/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87-javafx)
3. Используйте [Window.minimize(false)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/glass/ui/Window.java#Window.minimize%28boolean%29), чтобы развернуть окно.