# Приложение в панели задач

Tags: java, javafx

Как определить находится ли в данный момент приложение в панели задач или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня получилось так:

```
package ru.blestar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane()));
        primaryStage.show();

        Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);

                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        try {
                            System.out.println(isMinimized(primaryStage));
                        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public boolean isMinimized(Stage stage) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class c = Class.forName("com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage");
        java.lang.reflect.Field field = c.getDeclaredField("platformWindow");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        com.sun.glass.ui.Window w = (com.sun.glass.ui.Window) field.get(stage.impl_getPeer());
        return w.isMinimized();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Важно: метод isMinimized(Stage) необходимо вызывать в потоке приложения.

Так же можете посмотреть в сторону com.sun.javafx.stage.StageHelper, что бы избежать передачи Stage в роли параметра.